# Mining for bitcoins

Tags: miner-configuration

Does Bitcoin Core Wallet and Bitcoin Core Wallet Testnet both need to be running to mine?  I can't see or tell any Bitcoin earning mining is taking place.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin Core doesn't contain mining functionality any more.  It's not effectively possible to mine Bitcoin with software alone, not even on Testnet.

Any information telling you that you can earn Bitcoin just by running Bitcoin Core is utterly obsolete and should be ignored.